# Display product tags in a category page

Tags: tags

I can get tags in a view.phtml file like this:

```
<?php
$_tags = new Mage_Tag_Block_Product_List();
?>

Product Tags:
<ul class="product-tags">
<?php foreach($_tags->getTags() as $tag):?>
    <li><a href="<?=$tag->getTaggedProductsUrl()?>"><?=$tag->getName()?></a></li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

It works fine in a single product page.
But the code above doesn't work in categories; it returns error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getItems() on a non-object in
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Tag/Block/Product/List.php on line 45

As I understand the tags class cannot be instantiated.

But how can I display tags list in a category instead of products?
When I click on a tag I should get all products with this tag.
Also one tag must not be repeated twice.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

**edited**: 
I'll try to give more details...

There's a layered navigation on my home page called "Gifts". This is a simple filter with attributes.

When I choose some attritube(for example "gender - male") and press "Search" I redirect to a category "Gifts" and get result with products which have an attribute gender "male".
But on the first step when I get result I need to display NOT products, I need to display their tags.

For example, a product with attribute "male" can contain some tags "creative, relaxation, father, husband" etc...
Another product with attribute "male" can contain the same tags as above, but these tags won't be displayed again.
So we see only unique tags from all products.

On the second step when we click on tag "creative" we'll get all products with this tag.

Hope this explanation was helpful.

Comment: You want to see all tags or just the ones for the products in that specific category?

Comment: please clear the question?

Comment: Hi, guys. I want to see all tags only from a specific category, but tags with the same name must not repeat more than one time. I've added more info in my question. Hope it will help you to understand the meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can get tag list of a product using load of `tag/tag` resource model

Please try this code

```
$model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
      $TaGCollection= $model->getResourceCollection()
                ->addPopularity()
                ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
                ->addProductFilter($ProductId)
                ->setFlag('relation', true)
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->setActiveFilter()
                ->load();
```

My code only show approve tag.

Then you can get tags list by loop collection

```
$Tags=$TaGCollection->getItems();

if(count($Tags)):
       foreach ($Tags as $tag) {
               echo  $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl();
        echo $tag->getName();

        }
endif;
```

Comment: ok, i will give you sortly

Comment: hi check now...

Comment: thank you for help. Now I get error: Fatal error:  Call to undefined function getItems() on line with a string $Tags=$TaGCollection>getItems();

Comment: i will check........ give me 5min

Comment: silly mistake  > should be ->

Comment: yeah, you're right, should be ->. now no errors, thank you. but it's strange. I get 0 results, no tags and count returns zero

Comment: there are few filter on my collection one  approve tag,two store fiter remove those condition

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand what you mean under "two store filter remove those condition"

Comment: if you have multiple store then filter by current store

Comment: oh, no I don't have multiple store. Only one

Comment: then  remove this ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())

Comment: it didn't solve the issue because all my tags are approved in admin panel. But I commented ->addProductFilter($ProductId) line and it works now, but I don't know why. I should read  documentation about magento tags and learn the code. Thank you for the time you spend for me, I appreciate it. And thanks again for help. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

In Magento 1.9.2 we had to make a few changes to Amit's answer to get it working:

```
$id = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getId(), 'id');
$model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag'); 
$TaGCollection= $model-getResourceCollection() 
     ->addPopularity() 
     ->addProductFilter($id) 
     ->setFlag('relation', true) 
     ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()
     ->getStore()->getId()) 
     ->setActiveFilter() 
     ->load();
$Tags=$TaGCollection->getItems();
```