# All product tags cloud on the Magento start page

Tags: magento-1.9, product, tags

I use `Magento 1.9.3` and I would like to show all product tags on the start page.

Can somebody tell me the code I need to use and where I need to put in the code when I want to have the tag cloud shown in the footer of the start page?
[image: Tag Cloud]

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for get all tags on any page:

```
 $model = Mage::getModel('tag/tag');
  $TaGCollection= $model->getResourceCollection()
            ->addPopularity()
            ->addStatusFilter($model->getApprovedStatus())
            ->setFlag('relation', true)
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->setActiveFilter()
            ->load();

  $Tags=$TaGCollection->getItems();

  if(count($Tags)):
  foreach ($Tags as $tag) 
  {
       echo  $tag->getTaggedProductsUrl();
       echo $tag->getName();
  }
  endif;
```

Reference link: [Display product tags in a category page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40950/display-product-tags-in-a-category-page)

Comment: I saw this post already but this didn't work for me.

Comment: This code generates a link. What I want is the Tag Cloud itself right on the frontpage in the footer.

Comment: As per your question you want the tag display on homepage. Can you explain your question in detail? so i can get idea what you want.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I want to place the tag cloud as seen on the image at the footer of the magento start page.
Your first code just generates a link to the tag cloud but I want the tag cloud itself been shown on the footer of the start page.